# How to check if the parent component is a specific component?

Tags: reactjs, hierarchy

I'm pretty new to ReactJS, but I'm slowly getting behind it.

I want to create a smart component, it should detect if it is "inside" another component and render differently then.

Example:

```
<Menu>
  <Item />
</Menu>
```

Here, the item component should render as an **anchor**.

If used inside any other component or a div, it should simply render as a **div** as well.

Is there an easy way to check, if a component is inside another component in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by passing a prop, saying something about the context the component is being used in.

The simplest solution in your case would be to, whenever you use the item component in menu, you pass a prop.

```
render(){
  <Menu>
    <Item insideMenu={true} />
  </Menu>
}
```

Then inside the render you have two different return statements (depending on the insideMenu-prop).

```
// Item.jsx
render() {
  if(this.props.insideMenu)
    return (whatever)

  return (whateverElse)
}
```

Normally I wouldn't reccomend this though. Components, in my opinion, should be reuseable and generic if possible. In this case, I'd argue it would be better to have two components: `Item` and `MenuItem`. So then it would be

```
<Menu>
  <MenuItem>
</Menu>

<AnythingElse>
  <Item>
</AnythingElse>
```

Inside `MenuItem`, you may very well use the `Item` component as well, if they share the same behaviour. So in that case, `MenuItem` would render `Item`, as well as the extra behaviour required for the menu. Or simply wrap it inside an anchor-tag, if that's all there is to it.

Either solution works, but the latter is (in my opinion) cleaner. Less surprises, easier to read, and less that can go wrong (no need to juggle props).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I use your first approach at the moment (just give the item a href attribute and it will turn into a link). I don't want to create two seperate components, because I'm using Semantic UI.
There, the item in the menu uses the same classes (ui and item) as for other items othside the menu.
Only the used html tag changes the rendering of those items.

So, even if this is a bad example and you should use a seperate component, is there no way to access the parent form inside another component to check its class? Maybe handy for other components.